# Arithmetic operations for Array Indices in R

Tags: arrays, r

I create values

```
I=1:20
> I
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

I[10+1:20]
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I expected the array values 11:20 and nothing more.

However, if I use

```
I[(10+1):20]
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

I get the expected answer.

Any clues will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Sankar

Answer (score 1):

The `:` operator takes precedence. So running

```
1:5+5
```

will first compute the output of

```
1:5
```

then will add 5 to that array, yielding

```
6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

With `I[10+1:20]` you select elements 11 to 30 of a vector of length 20, so you get 10 times an `NA` (for elements 21, 22, ... that do not exist). In `I[(10+1):20]` you just select elements 11 to 20.

Comment: Thanks very much Sacha and Jeff